# Defining Likelihood function for a given time series

Tags: time-series, bayesian

I have a set of observations ${y_1,...y_n}$ generated from a given time series $$y_t = \phi y_{t-1} + \epsilon_t$$

where $\epsilon_t$ are independent and identically distributed generated from a Gaussian distribution $N(0, \sigma^2)$ and a prior for $\phi$ is given as also being normally distributed with parameters $N(0,\sigma^2_\phi)$

I am trying to calculate a conditional distribution for $\phi$ but am unable to define an appropriate likelihood for the given data. I am aware that the distribution for the likelihood is a normal distribution but I am unable to define its parameters.

Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: Hi: Google for   " Bayesian analysis of an AR(1) model " and an arxiv paper will come up. I didn't read it but it looks relevant.

Comment: Why I didnt read that paper I do not know. Indeed it gives a definition of the likelihood for this timeseries. Thank you for recommending that (and doing the google search for me)!

Comment: no problem. you're welcome and I'm glad to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The likelihood for this timeseries was defined by Hamilton 1994 as
[image: definition of likelihood for AR1 timeseries].

Reference found in the following [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1611.08747)